# Yii - how to access virtual attributes on search

Tags: php, yii

I can best explain this through code:

```
class Entity extends CActiveRecord {

   public $fullname;

   public function tableName() {
    return 'tbl_entities';     
   }

   //single table inheritance
   protected function instantiate($attributes){
    if(!isset($attributes['type']))
        $class=get_class($this);
    else
        $class= $attributes['type'];
        $model=new $class(null);
        return $model;
    }

    //other irrelevant stuff
}

class User extends Entity {
    public function getFullname() {
        return $this->name_first. ' ' .$this->name_last;
    }

    public function defaultScope() {
        return [
            'condition'=>"type='User'", 
        ];  
    }

    //other irrelevant stuff
}

//The code where its called
$model = User::model()->findByPk($id);
if($model) {
    echo $model->getFullname();
    echo $model->fullname;
}
```

The `getFullname()` function returns the name, but the `fullname` returns empty. What can I do to fix this? Does it not read it because of the getFullname()?

- Gasim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first PHP tries to find attribute in your class. PHP looks for **$fullname** in your class (and also parent classes) and returns value stored in **$fullname**.

If you don't have **$fullname** attribute in your class,  PHP will try to run magic method **__get()**. This magic method runs your virtual attribute getter.

So don't give same names to class attributes and virtual attribute methods.

Comment: i just added afterFind that assigns the fullname to it and it worked :D

Answer (score 1):

`$fullname` returns empty because it isn't set. are you sure the `$fullname` is set on a find? if you want the `$model->fullname;` to call your getter, then you should read this forum post:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8162-model-getter-methods/

Answer (score 1):

`$fullname` returns empty because its not a `tbl_entities` property. When you query an AR object using `find()`. All table properties can be accessed.

```
$model = User::model()->findByPk($id);

// Assuming that `tbl_entities` has the columns `name_first` and `name_last`
$model->name_first // returns a value saved on the table.
$model->name_last // returns a value saved on the table.
$model->fullname //Does not return a value because its not in the `tbl_entities`
```